# How do I underline this block

Tags: html, css

I have this block of my tumblr template:

> {block:IfNotEndlessScroll}{block:Pagination}{block:PreviousPage}página
>   anterior{/block:PreviousPage} {block:NextPage}próxima
>   página{/block:NextPage}{/block:Pagination}{/block:IfNotEndlessScroll}

I would like to know how to make the text "Próxima pagina" and "Página anterior"underlined...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What language is that? Show me some HTML and I'll show you some CSS.

Comment: {block:IfNotEndlessScroll}{block:Pagination}<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:10px;  letter-spacing:1px; font-style:italic;font-size:11px; line-height:15px; "><div style="float:left">{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}">página anterior</a>{/block:PreviousPage}</div> <div style="float:right;">{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}">próxima página</a>{/block:NextPage}</div></div>{/block:Pagination}{/block:IfNotEndlessScroll}

Answer (score 0):

From http://buildthemes.tumblr.com/ch1/variables-blocks

In your theme's CSS file

```
.pagination > span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

In your tumblr template

```
{block:IfNotEndlessScroll}
    <div class="pagination">
    {block:Pagination}
        <span>{block:PreviousPage}página anterior{/block:PreviousPage}</span>
        <span>{block:NextPage}próxima página{/block:NextPage}</span>
    {/block:Pagination}
    </div>
{/block:IfNotEndlessScroll}
```

Comment: I cant seem to apply it. Here is the live version www.litemia.tumblr.com

Comment: Have you got endless scroll enabled?

Answer (score 0):

```
a[href="{PreviousPage}"] {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;}

a[href="{NextPage}"] {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;}
```

Comment: An explanation please ? Answers are better received when they also include a short description of what the code is actually doing.